# Operand data type NULL is invalid for max operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This code works ok:

```
select fk, max(case when 1 = 0 then 1 else null end) maxx
    from (values(1, null), (1, null)) x(fk, a) 
    group by fk;
```

output:

```
fk          maxx
----------- -----------
1           NULL
```

with:

`Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`

But this code:

```
select fk, max(a) maxx
    from (values(1, null), (1, null)) x(fk, a)
    group by fk;
```

give error:

`Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Operand data type NULL is invalid for max operator.`

In both cases sql server calculate `max` from `null` and `null`? Isn't it?

Comment: You can make the 2nd work by explicitly casting null to a datatype. `select fk, max(a) maxx
from (values(1, CAST (NULL AS varchar(25)) ), (1, CAST (NULL AS varchar(25)) )) x(fk, a)
group by fk;`  You can't get max of null when datatype for column is unknown.  You'll note when you try and create a table that only has nulls; it fails as well because again datatype is unknown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first case you implicitly specify a datatype, namely an integer. This is inferred from the `then` which will never be reached. The fact that the `then` will not be executed, doesn't matter for sql server. [In fact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql), the way sql server determines the return type: "the highest [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) type from the set of types in *result_expressions* and the *optional else_result_expression*". So the return type is chosen *before* actual execution, from all potential datatypes to be returned in the `then` and `else`. in other words, before sql server 'realises' that some statements cannot possibly be reached.

Since the datatype is known, `max` can be applied.

In the second case you don't specify a datatype, so sql server can not know how to implement the `max`. A `max` for `varchar` is different than a `max` for integers.

Answer (score 1):

That is neat. In my opinion it probably *should* be implicitly converted to `int`.

The docs mention this for `inserts`:

> the values specified in a multi-row `insert` statement follow the data type conversion properties of the `union all` syntax.
>   - [Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)

---

Both of these turn the `null` value to an `int`:

```
select null as MyNullCol
into dbo.tmp
union all 
select null as MyNullCol

select fk, a
into dbo.tmp2
from (values(1, null), (1, null)) x(fk, a)

select c.name, t.name
from sys.columns c
  inner join sys.types t
    on c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
where c.name in ('a','mynullcol')
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VWMT9189

returns

```
+-----------+------+
|   name    | name |
+-----------+------+
| MyNullCol | int  |
| a         | int  |
+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Yes, it is very strange. My test `select fk, a INTO #T from (values(1, null), (1, null)) x(fk, a) exec tempdb.sys.sp_columns #T drop table #T` also give me `int` for `a`...

Comment: Good point, although in my opinion your examples should give an error. If you try to create a table with `null` as datatype it is also not implicitly converted to an `int`. But that's how sql server been build, I suppose.

Comment: Probably this cast occurs only when data insertion happens.

Comment: @HoneyBadger That was my opinion because that is how similar situations are handled. If each were handled in the same way that would be fine with me!

Comment: The documentation explicitly talks about "a multi-row `INSERT` statement", which this is *not*. As long as you don't use the values to create a table, conversion is not involved. `select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(a, 'BaseType') from (values(null)) x(a)` returns `NULL`, same as `select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(NULL, 'BaseType')`. A solitary `NULL` is not implicitly converted to type `INT`; it really has no type. It's just that in most cases, it doesn't stay that way for long.